# How to send images to back in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to send the sun and the sunrays to the back of the stage:

```
function CreateRays():Shape
{
    var ray:Shape = new Shape();

    ray.graphics.beginFill(0xFF9900,.5);
    ray.graphics.lineStyle(1,0xFF9900,.5);
    ray.graphics.lineTo(600,-20);
    ray.graphics.lineTo(600,20);
    ray.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
    ray.graphics.endFill();

    return ray;
}

var sun:Shape = new Shape();

sun.graphics.beginFill(0xFF9900,1);
sun.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,30);
sun.graphics.endFill();

addChild(sun); 
setChildIndex(sun, 0);
```

I saw that `setChildIndex(sun, 0);` should do it, but it isn't working.

Comment: What are you calling `addChild()` on? You will only be able to send the items as far back as their parent object is.

Comment: Nothing afaik, I couldn't find any method that would let me send anything to the back without it being a child...Is there no way to send something to the very back of the stage easily?

Comment: The stage is the root object on the display list. You need to call `addChild(sun)` on an object that is on the display list for the sun to show up. Is the code you posted located on a frame, or in an `.as` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by your confusion as to what you are adding the objects to and the syntax of the code you provided, I am guessing you are already on the top level object. Try this:

```
this.addChildAt(sun,0);
```

That will add `sun` to the parent object as the very first item (first = back, last = front). If I'm correct as to which object you are currently in, it should also be the very first item on the stage.

Make sure you read up on things like this before using them: [DisplayObjectContainer.addChildAt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChildAt%28%29)